# Do you still hear the expression 'make no bones (about something)' in American English nowadays?

Tags: word-usage

Defined by cambridge as follows:

> **make no bones about sth**.
>   not to try to hide your feelings:
>   *He made no bones about his dissatisfaction with the service.*

Here's what a search on [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Make%20no%20bones&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=5&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2CMake%20no%20bones%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmake%20no%20bones%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMake%20no%20bones%3B%2Cc0) yields.

Comment: "Make no bones about it" is still heard, though only occasionally.  Other forms are rarer.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Doesn't the Ngram answer your question immediately?

Comment: Comparing BrE and AmE corpuses using [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=make+no+bones+about&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmake%20no%20bones%20about%3B%2Cc0) it seems to me the idiom is primarily *British*. And doubtless it was somewhat "regional" (or peculiar to certain sociolinguistic groups primarily defined by class, age, etc.), before becoming much more widespread during the social melting pot of WW2. Curiously though, the usage is now tailing off somewhat faster in BrE than in AmE.

Comment: Google will let you search for a phrase on a specific website, so pick your favorite news source, magazine, or website, e.g. [New York Times](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22make+no+bones%22+site%3Anytimes.com) - still used although a lot of the results are quite old.

Answer (score 0):

According to [The Phrase Finder](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/make-no-bones-about.html) the idiom is not as common as it used to be, though it came back into fashion in the ‘80s. I’d  define it as a literary expression.

> 'Making bones' is usually expressed in the negative. There are rare occurrences of people being described as 'making bones' about this or that, and an early example comes from Richard Simpson's The School of Shakspere, 1878:
>
> - *"Elizabeth was thus making huge bones of sending some £7000 over for the general purposes of the government in Ireland."*
>
> ***”Make no bones about it” is now rather archaic and heard less often than before.***  It did return briefly during the 1980s, as an example of the 'waiter, I'll have a crocodile sandwich, and make it snappy' form of joke. 'Waiter, I'll have tomato soup and make no bones about it' linked neatly back to the phrase's culinary origin.